# How to print one line after the matching pattern using awk sed or cut command

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, sh

I want to print the content of text file till one character of pattern matching. I have used `awk` command but failed to get the desired output.

File:

```
>cat abc1.txt
2020-05-02 07:48:44+0000
```

What I have tried:

```
>cat abc1.txt | awk '{print $1}'
2020-05-02
```

Desired output:

```
2020-05-02 07:48
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please fix the title of the question

Comment: One line after or one character after? What "pattern" do you want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've given a fair representation of the nature of your problem, you don't need `awk`, `sed` or `cut`.  Here are four ways to process your text using only `bash` built-ins:

#### 1. `bash` Regular Expressions

```sh
[[ $(<./abc1.txt) =~ (^.+): ]] && printf %s "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

- **`$(<./abc1.txt)`**: reads in the contents of the file `abc1.txt` and is more efficient that `cat` according to `bash`'s own `man` page
- **`=~`**: regular expression operator
- **`(^.+):`**: capture every character from the beginning of the line to the character immediately *preceding* the final colon
- **`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`**: stores the list of substrings matched by the regular expression pattern; the first capture group (inside the pattern's parentheses) is stored at index 1

#### 2. `bash` Parameter Substitution

```sh
: "$(<./abc1.txt)"
printf %s "${_%:*}"
```

- **`${_%:*}`:** the underscore references the argument from the previous command, i.e. the file contents; and the substitution strips everything from the final colon to the end of the string

#### 3. `date`

Since it's very clear you're working with a date, and one that is expressed in a well-defined format (ISO-8601), the `date` command can do what's designed to do:

```sh
# -j flag available on macOS:
date -jf '%F %T%z' "$(<./abc1.txt)" +'%F %R'
# -d option on other systems:
# [credit: @WalterA (see comments below)]
date -d "$(<./abc1.txt)" +"%F %R"
```

This parses a date using the input format string `"%F %T%z"` that describes what each component of the date string represents (see [*Linux Programmer's Manual - `STRFTIME(3)`*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)), and reformats in using the output string `"%F %R"`, which in this case represents a date string similar to the original but without the time zone and without the *seconds*.

#### 4. `printf`

`printf` is made for formatting text.  So here it just formats the text to display the first 16 characters (it actually limits the column width of the first field to 16-character widths, but that is blah):

```sh
printf '%16.16s\n' "$(<./abc1.txt)"
```

#### 5. Substring

Similar to (4), but using parameter substitution:

```sh
: "$(<./abc1.txt)"
printf "${_:0:16}"
```

---

Apart from `(3)`¹ none make calls to external programs or commands, which affords more portability, greater reliability/robustness, more efficient execution (generally speaking, but this won't be measurable unless you're processing hundreds or more dates or files), and fewer system resources.

`awk` and `sed` are powerful big-guns, and not particularly light-weight tools (they're both fully-fledged, Turing-complete scripting languages in their own right).  Don't reach for them just because everyone else does, or because it's what you know: learn what `bash` can do as a shell, and you'll benefit a lot down the line.

¹ <sub>*Some systems include a version of `printf` that can format dates using any of the flags recognised by `strftime`, and would be a good alternative to `date` if available.  `printf --help` or `man bash` (under the section about builtins) will reveal if this option exists.*</sub>

Comment: My `date` doesn't know `-j`, I needed `date -d "$(<./abc1.txt)" +'%F %R'`. I am most impressed by your first 2 solutions, I can'r understand why nobody else upvoted your answer.

Comment: @WalterA Thanks a lot for the upvote, and for the note on `date`.  I hope you don’t object to my including your solution in my answer, where I’ve added it to mine credited to you.  If you wish me to remove this, e.g. should you prefer to add your own answer, let me know and I’ll roll back my edit. I’m guessing the `-j` option is specific to macOS.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo '2020-05-02 07:48:44+0000' | awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $1, $2}'
2020-05-02 07:48
$ echo '2020-05-02 07:48:44+0000' | cut -d: -f1-2
2020-05-02 07:48
```

You can change the default field separator to `:` character and print first two fields

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `rev` + `awk` where it makes our substitution easier.

```
rev Input_file | awk '{sub(/[^:]*:/,"")} 1' | rev
```

***3rd solution:*** With `sed`'s temp buffer capability.

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*/\1/' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** If your Input_file always have same format Input and you need not to verify about date's syntax then try.

```
awk 'match($0,/^.*:/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

***5th solution:*** Adding only substitute operation awk solution.

```
awk '{sub(/:[0-9]{2}\+.*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***6th solution:*** Set field separator value and print needed fields only.

```
awk -F' |:' '{print $1,$2":"$3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an input and output field separator (`:`) and remove last column with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {NF--; print}' abc1.txt
```

or shorter:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {NF--}1' abc1.txt
```

Output:

```
2020-05-02 07:48
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use `sub` function in awk to remove everything after last occurrence of `:`:

```
awk '{sub(/:[^:]*$/, "")} 1' abc1.txt
```

```
2020-05-02 07:48
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print the content of text file till **one** character of pattern matching.

The regular expression that matches what you want to keep:

```
[^:]*:[^:]*
```

Two equivalent sed commands to keep only what is matched by that:

```
sed 's|\([^:]*:[^:]*\).*|\1|'
sed -E 's|([^:]*:[^:]*).*|\1|'
```

Sample output:

```
$ echo '2020 07:48:40:40+0000'|sed 's|\([^:]*:[^:]*\).*|\1|'
2020 07:48
```